# calling Access query from Excel macro

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel-2010, ms-access-2010

I have a VBA macro in Excel that calls a query in an Access database (.mdb).  However, the Access has been updated to a .accdb file and I don't know how to change up the macro (and/or include any libraries as I don't truly understand that part yet) so that the code will work.

Here is the current "header" code:

```
'Step 1: Declare your variables
Dim MyDatabase As DAO.Database
Dim MyQueryDef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim MyRecordset As DAO.Recordset


'Step 2: Identify the database and query
Set MyDatabase = DBEngine.OpenDatabase("C:\Users\Ben\Google Drive\Database\Production\FOREAL PROD.mdb")
```

Comment: Did you try updating the filename in the `Set MyDatabase` statement and running the code? If so, what happened?

Comment: Yes.  I get an unrecognizable database error.  I think it's because MyDatabase is a DAO.Database and it needs to be ADO.  But I don't understand all that.

Comment: DAO still works with .accdb files if you have recent enough components (for the ACE database engine). What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: [start here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) , DAO isnt your database - its the driver , [look here too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164825(v=office.10).aspx)

Comment: mehow.. I unfortunately don't understand the first link.  Is it potentially that I am not using the correct libraries?  I don't which to use or why.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an "unrecognizable database format" error then your Excel project may be using an older DAO (Data Access Objects) reference that does not know how to deal with .accdb files.

In the VBA window, choose `Tools > References...`. If you see an old DAO reference like...

"Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library"

...then that could explain the problem.

You'll want to upgrade that old DAO reference to this one...

"Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library"

...and to do that you'll need to download and install the Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).